# Java problema Serie

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer el siguiente problema "Desarrolle un programa en Java que implemente la aproximación a la función seno para un ángulo x en grados mediante un polinomio de Taylor" esto fue lo que hice pero no entiendo el error que me marca al momento de compilar, si saben algún cambio o otra forma de resolver este problema me serviría mucho.

```
// Serie de Taylor

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Taylor {

public static float po(float b, int p) {

    float r = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= p; k++) {
        r = r * b;
    }
    return (r);

}

public static double fac(int n) {
    double aux = 1;
    for (int a = 2; a <= n; a++) {
        aux *= a;
    }
    return aux;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    float seno = 0;
    int cnt2 = 1;

    System.out.println("Ingrese el angulo en radianes: ");
    float x = sc.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de elementos de la serie de Taylor");
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    for (int cnt1 = 1; cnt1 <= n; cnt1++) {
        seno = seno + po(-1, cnt1 + 1) * po(x, cnt2) / fac(cnt2);
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 2;
    }
    System.out.println("El seno del angulo es: ", x, seno);
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido, cual es el problema en el còdigo?, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: al momento de compilar me dice que quiero pasar de float a double